# Modify x & y using range() to create grid using Python turtle

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

How do I modify the x and y in the `range()` function to create a grid using turtle?  I am trying to create a grid of squares with a set spacing between each using turtle graphics. Right now I'm using this:

```
blocks = turtle.Turtle()
blocks.color("gray")
blocks.speed(0)
blocks.shape("square")
blocks.turtlesize(1.9)
blocks.penup()
blocks.setpos(-212, 130)
blocks_x = 85
blocks_y = 85
for pos in range(4):
    blocks.setpos(blocks.xcor() + blocks_x, blocks.ycor())
    blocks.stamp()

blocks.setpos(blocks.xcor(), blocks.ycor() - blocks_y)

for pos in range(4):
    blocks.setpos(blocks.xcor() + blocks_x, blocks.ycor())
    blocks.stamp()

blocks.setpos(blocks.xcor(), blocks.ycor() - blocks_y)

for pos in range(4):
    blocks.setpos(blocks.xcor() + blocks_x, blocks.ycor())
    blocks.stamp()

blocks.setpos(blocks.xcor(), blocks.ycor() - blocks_y)

for pos in range(4):
    blocks.setpos(blocks.xcor() + blocks_x, blocks.ycor())
    blocks.stamp()

blocks.setpos(blocks.xcor(), blocks.ycor() - blocks_y)
```

It does what I want it to do but, I'd like to know if there is a way to modify the the y coordinate after all x's have been printed so I can use the `range()` function once?

Comment: You say that your code "does what [you] want it to do", but I don't think that's correct. The code you show draws boxes in a stair-step style (a row of four, then another row of four offset, then another row offset some more). If you want a regular rectangular grid, the natural way to do that is in a pair of nested loops, but I'm not actually sure what you want, since the text of your question doesn't match the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing from your code and description you want something like the following where the x position *and* the y position are controlled by nested `for` loops:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

BLOCKS_X, BLOCKS_Y = 85, 85
BLOCK_SIZE = 38

CURSOR_SIZE = 20

screen = Screen()

blocks = Turtle('square', visible=False)
blocks.penup()
blocks.color('gray')
blocks.speed('fastest')
blocks.turtlesize(BLOCK_SIZE / CURSOR_SIZE)

x_start, y_start = -1.5 * BLOCKS_X, 1.5 * BLOCKS_Y

blocks.setpos(x_start, y_start)

for _ in range(4):
    for _ in range(4):
        blocks.stamp()
        blocks.forward(BLOCKS_X)

    blocks.setpos(x_start, blocks.ycor() - BLOCKS_Y)

screen.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: Yes! This is perfect. I did not realize you could stack those functions. The way you wrote that shows me a few other shortcuts I could be taking as well. Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 0):

try

```
turtle.goto([x coordinate],[y coordinate])
```

this will basically teleport the turtle to those coordinates

Comment: This is very helpful as well!